# Calling WCF from Curl:

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I've been facing lots of problem with a WebService implementation.

I created a .NET WebService that will be called by QAD ERP. I've installed the Web Service on our server that can be accessed by the following address:  http://187.72.208.85/QADWs/Service.svc

The ERP is calling the Web Service sending the XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header></soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <qdoc:Item xmlns:qdoc="http://tempuri.org/IService/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <qdoc:file>
        <qdoc:operation>A</qdoc:operation>
        <qdoc:ptAdded>2015-06-09</qdoc:ptAdded>
        <qdoc:ptCdCmmt/>
        <qdoc:ptCdRef>DI</qdoc:ptCdRef>    
    </qdoc:file>
    </qdoc:Item>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The webservice code is set up as below:

IService

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Item(byte[] file);
}
```

Service

```
public class Service : IService
{  
    public void Item(byte[] file)
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:/ws/Item.xml", file);
    }
}
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.5"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>    
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I am calling the WebService from curl using the following code:

```
curl http://187.72.208.85/QADWs/Service.svc -X POST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -H "SOAPAction: 'http://tempuri.org/IService/Item'" -T ITEM.xml
```

Then, it returned the follow error:

"The message with Action http://tempuri.org/IService/Item; cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.
This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None)."

Could you guys help me how to figure it out?

Comment: The service reachable at http://187.72.208.85/QADWs/Service.svc has completly different methods than the methodes you are using. These methodes are Addition, Item and Substract. Looks like you didn't update the service or installed the wrong service.

Comment: Yes! It's because I've shown only the Item Method. The others I deleted before posting here. The method I am trying to reach is the Item

Comment: Did you remove the service? I just tried it and recieved an error "no endpoint"